# React - move row of data to new table based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a table of schedules that is populated by a series of api calls.
I'm using [SUIR](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) to render each schedule and some identifying information in a [`<Table>`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/). I added a [`slider`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox/#types-slider) in an unmarked column before each schedule. This will represent the boolean option to "export" the schedule.

```
  <Table.Body>
    {Object.values(schedules).map(
      ({ id, startTime, selfUri, status }) => {
        return (
          <Table.Row>
            <Checkbox slider onChange={this.slider} />
            <Table.Cell>{id}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              {format(startTime, "MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss A")}
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{selfUri}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{status}</Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        );
      }
    )}
  </Table.Body>
```

I currently have this `slider` change handler

```
  slider = () =>
    this.setState({ exportSlider: !this.state.exportSlider }, () => {
      console.log("slider --> ", this.state.exportSlider);
    });
```

But this only keeps track of one slider state. How can I keep track of each slider state from each corresponding schedule? And how can I take the `slider === true` schedules and add them to a new table to be exported?

I have a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmmm0l2mmv) that has a few schedules and the slider functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abstract your table row into a separate component. Then you can have every row track it's own slider state. Example of a component like this could be the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Checkbox } from "semantic-ui-react";
import format from "date-fns/format";

export default class TableRowWithSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      exportSlider: false
    };
  }
  slider = () => {
    this.setState({ exportSlider: !this.state.exportSlider }, () => {
      console.log("slider --> ", this.state.exportSlider);
      const { id, slide } = this.props;
      slide({ id, isExported: this.state.exportSlider });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { id, startTime, selfUri, status } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Table.Row>
          <Checkbox slider onChange={this.slider} />
          <Table.Cell>{id}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{format(startTime, "MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss A")}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{selfUri}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{status}</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Check out the sandbox for the full solution: [click](https://codesandbox.io/s/30xqrorpw6). The parent component is keeping the state stored of all the schedule ids that should be exported. The child component AKA `TableRowWithSlider` calls it's own slide handler as well as the parent's slide handler to pass it's id and toggle state.

The table body looks like this:

```
<Table.Body>
  {Object.values(schedules).map(
    ({ id, startTime, selfUri, status }) => {
      return (
        <TableRowWithSlider
          id={id}
          startTime={startTime}
          selfUri={selfUri}
          status={status}
          slide={this.slider.bind(this)}
        />
      );
    }
  )}
</Table.Body>
```

And the parent's slide handler looks like this:

```
slider = ({ id, isExported }) => {
  if (isExported === true) {
    this.setState(
      {
        scheduleIdsToExport: [id, ...this.state.scheduleIdsToExport]
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.scheduleIdsToExport)
    );
  } else {
    const newArray = this.state.scheduleIdsToExport.filter(
      storedId => storedId !== id
    );
    this.setState(
      {
        scheduleIdsToExport: newArray
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.scheduleIdsToExport)
    );
  }
};
```

Check full solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/30xqrorpw6)

Comment: And then just import `<TableRowWithSlider>` into `<Table.Body>` of my main component? Do you mind sharing an updated sandbox with your proposed change?

Comment: @DJ2 I've updated the answer with a link to the sandbox containing the full solution